# How to print a react component in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Can anyone tell me how to print a react component using typescript on a button click ? I am pretty new to react and typescript and want to print a component in typescript on the click of a button .

Comment: What do you mean by "print"? Are you trying to put some debugging details in to the console? Are you trying to put ink on paper? Something else?

Comment: Do you mean to "conditionally render"?  Your button click would set some state value to `true` and your returned JSX would render the component only if that state value is `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna provide print functionality of your components to the users I had a great experience with this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print setup is very easy. Here https://codesandbox.io/s/rzdhd you can try a demo